# Arduino program to reverse a string and turn it to uppercase

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

This code is supposed to return the string inversed but for some reason the loop isn't working (i picked len=4 to simplify it, it's sizeof(s); originally)

```
char s[100];
char RevStr[100];
int availableBytes;
String mystring;
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
int len;
int j = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    availableBytes = Serial.available();
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    for (int i = 0; i < availableBytes; i++) {
      s[i] = Serial.read();
    }
//len=sizeof(s);

// a loop to reverse the string

    len = 4;
    //Serial.println(len);
    for (k = len - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
      j++;
      RevStr[j] = s[k];
      //Serial.println(RevStr[j]);
      //Serial.print(s[k]);
    }
    RevStr[len + 1] = '\0';

    mystring = RevStr;
    mystring.toUpperCase();
    Serial.print(mystring);

  }
}
```

Comment: print `s`. I guess it is incomplete. Serial data don't arrive so fast that you could read them like this. use `readBytesUntil`

Comment: "isn't working" isn't a proper problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Serial data don't arrive so fast that you could read them like you do. [readBytesUntil](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytesuntil/) waits for the next character and terminates on termination character or [timeout](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/settimeout/).

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char s[64];
    int length = Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', s, sizeof(s));
    if (length > 0 && s[length - 1] == '\r') {
      length--;
    }
    s[length] = 0; // terminating zero
    Serial.println(s);
    char s2[64];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      s2[i] = toupper(s[length - 1 - i]);
    }
    s2[length] = 0;
    Serial.println(s2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize the character array (don't initialize it) you can't rule out the `'\0'` character in the memory area reserved for the character array; *the compiler doesn't automatically clear the memory space allocated for you unless you use custom compilation flags*.

When there is a problem, I recommend looking for ways to isolate the problem. Below is a way I developed to solve this problem.

I defined a static class in the `StringManager.hpp` file:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"

class StringManager
{
  public:
    static void Initialize(char *original, char ch, int size);
    static void Write(char *original, String message, int size);
    static void Reverse(char *original, char *reverse, int size);
};
```

I implemented the methods in the `StringManager.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include "StringManager.hpp"

void StringManager::Initialize(char *original, char ch, int size)
{
  if(size > 0 && original != NULL)
  {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; ++i)
    {
      original[i] = ch;
    }
    original[size - 1] = '\0';
  }
}

void StringManager::Write(char *original, String message, int size)
{
  if((original != NULL) && (message != NULL))
  {
    for(int i = 0 ; original[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {
      if(message[i] == '\0')
        original[i] = '.';
      else
        original[i] = message[i];
    }
  }
  original[size - 1] = '\0';
}

void StringManager::Reverse(char *original, char *reverse, int size)
{ 
  if(size > 0 && original != NULL && reverse != NULL)
  {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
    {
      reverse[i] = original[size - i - 2];
    }

    reverse[size - 1] = '\0';
  }
}
```

The application code (*.ino) is available below:

```cpp
#include "StringManager.hpp"

#define SIZE 10

char original[SIZE], reverse[SIZE];
String result, message = "ABCDEF";

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
  
void loop() 
{
   StringManager::Initialize(original, '.', SIZE);  
   StringManager::Initialize(reverse, '.', SIZE);
   
   StringManager::Write(original, message, SIZE); 
   Serial.println(original);
   StringManager::Reverse(original, reverse, SIZE);  
   Serial.println(reverse);
   
   result = reverse;
   result.toLowerCase();
   Serial.println(result);
   
  delay(1000);
}
```

Application test image is available below:

[image]

Comment: so much code for such a simple task. 1) what should initialize do? 2) String has toCharArray(). 3) you know a system where char is more than 1 byte?